# Forward declaring a function in a namespace inside another function in that namespace

Tags: c++, visual-c++, namespaces, function-prototypes

I have two source files, `a.cpp` and `b.cpp`. In `a.cpp`, I have a function, `foo`:

```
namespace ns { void foo() { std::cout << "foo!"; } }
```

In `b.cpp`, I have another function in namespace `ns` in which I'd like to prototype and call `foo`:

```
namespace ns
{

void bar()
{
    void foo();
    foo();       
}

}
```

While the above is syntactically valid, it leads the compiler to think that `foo` is in the global namespace (or at least that's what I've deduced from the linker errors I get when I do this). My first two ideas to fix that were `void ns::foo();` and `namespace ns { void foo(); }`, but neither is valid. Is it possible to correctly prototype this function inside `bar`?

Note that I know I could simply move this to the file scope or a header file, there have been many questions asked about this, but I want to specifically prototype it inside another function. My compiler is MSVC 14.0 with the latest update.

**EDIT:** Based on some tests I've done and our discussion in the comments, I believe this is an MSVC bug. Compare:

```
namespace ns
{

void bar()
{
    void foo();   // link error, MSVC assumes global namespace
    foo();
}

void foo() { }

} // namespace ns
```

This fails, as stated previously. However, moving the prototype out of the function makes MSVC correctly place the prototyped function in the enclosing namespace:

```
namespace ns
{

void foo();   // all fine
void bar()
{
    foo();
}

void foo() { }

} // namespace ns
```

Comment: @JoachimPileborg It is not valid inside a function. http://www.cpp.sh/3g3hu

Comment: The following compiles and runs fine; is this not what you want? https://gist.github.com/jncornett/8e4d85e6008087438cf5

Comment: @JoelCornett It compiles fine, but doesn't link, at least not for me (MSVC 14.0).

Comment: @szczurcio Seems like a MSVC error then.  Tried it here on gcc and clang and it works (Joel Cornett's https://gist.github.com/jncornett/8e4d85e6008087438cf5)

Comment: The Standard is quite clear: *"When a block scope declaration of an entity with linkage is not found to refer to some other declaration,
then that entity is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. However such a declaration does not introduce the member name in its namespace scope."* [basic.link]p7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard is clear about this point:

> **3.3.2/11:** (..)  Function declarations at block scope and variable declarations with the extern specifier at block scope **refer to**
>   declarations that are **members of an enclosing namespace** (...)

Consequently:

```
void bar()
{
    void foo();   // should refer to ns::foo() according to 3.3.2/11
    foo();
}
```

and the linking should refer to the separately compiled function which has the same signature:

> **1.3.17 signature:** `<function>` name, parameter type list , and enclosing namespace (if any) [Note: Signatures are used as a basis for
>   name mangling and linking.—end note ]

Comment: That's what I thought, which is why I blamed MSVC for this behavior. +1 for standard reference.